# Is there any possibility to execute function only once?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in JavaScript which is hiding some content. I actually want to hide-the content, before button is clicked. I know that maybe I could have empty elements and fill them after I click that button, but this looks like easier way.

I want to execute this function from the time user enters the page by the time he click on some button - then never, even after refresh.

Is it possible somehow?

```js
function hideTheTable(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].style.visibility = "hidden"
  document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].style.visibility = "hidden"
  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].style.visibility = "hidden"
  document.getElementById('info').style.visibility = "hidden"
}

hideTheTable();
```

Comment: You can use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to track if the user clicked the button, or you can store that information in your server, depending on your architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `localStorage` to store whether or not the function has already been run.

```
function hideTheTable(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('hideTableFlag')){
        localStorage.setItem('hideTableFlag', true);
        console.log('function run')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, by adding a cookie that returns if user entered the page before:

```
// first lets create a helper function that lets us retreive a cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
// setting cookie
// if you need the function to load when the page loads
window.onload = (){
document.cookie = "enteredbefore=true; path=/";
};
// else if you need to call it when user clicks on button (define your button)
mybutton.onclick = (){
document.cookie = "enteredbefore=true; path=/";
};
// now we make if else statment
if(getCookie(enteredbefore) == ""){
// call your function
hideTheTable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was just looking for a more simple solution and actually wanted something, that will work for one instance, it doesn't need to be working, when user comes for second time. But thanks!